# How to calculate months between two dates including the starting date month?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to apply the straight line deprecation for this, I've two date starting date 2018-09-17 (YYYY-MM-DD) ending date 2018-12-30. I need answer in months which is 4 not 3 because, it give me 3.

I've tried starting date 2018-09-01 and ending date 2019-01-01. It give me correct answer 4 what I want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

## It give me answer 4

```
$d1 = new DateTime("2018-09-01");
$d2 = new DateTime("2019-01-01");
echo $d1->diff($d2)->m . " Months";
```

## I need answer 4 for these two date

**2018-17-09 to 2018-30-12**

Is there any way to get the answer 4 in months including the starting date. I am getting the answer 4 from these date (2018-09-01) to (2019-01-01). In short, I want to include the current date month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Carbon`:

```php
use \Carbon\Carbon;
$from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', '2018-17-09');
$to = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', '2018-30-12')->addMonth();

return $to->diffInMonths($from);
```

[Live demo here](https://implode.io/HGiXz9)

Comment: You have add the month, but it confuse me

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) method and pass `"n"` to it this will get the month as a numeric value then you can define your logic.

An example:

```php
$date1 = (new Datetime("2018-09-17"))->format("n"); 
$date2 = (new Datetime("2018-12-30"))->format("n"); 
echo $date2 - $date1 + 1;
```